# Invert everything on page except ::selection

Tags: css

I want to invert page but also I want text selection to stay as it is. I tried to use `::selection` to exclude it but didn't work.

Here is my css code for inversion:

```
html {
 background-color: #131313 !important;
 filter: contrast(85%) brightness(100%) invert(100%);
 -webkit-filter: contrast(85%) brightness(100%) invert(100%);
}
```

And here is code for tags that I want to exclude:

```
em, img, svg, image, video, audio, embed, iframe, object, button, canvas, .sidebar-description
{
  filter: invert(100%) !important;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a chained `:not` selector call. Here is a simple example which will turn all the font colour on a page red, except for links and buttons.

```
*:not(a):not(button) {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is it for your use case:

```
*:not(em):not(img):not(svg):not(image):not(video):not(audio):not(embed):not(iframe):not(object):not(button):not(canvas):not(.sidebar-description)
{
    filter: invert(100%) !important;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%) !important;
}
```

This may need to be tweaked depending on the specific setup you're in but this looks like what you need to use.

Comment: How can I say this about ::selection, this way? -> ``*:not(::selection)``